# unable to fetch data in dropdownlist using ng-repeat

Tags: angular

i am trying to display a dropdownlist from a list of values in angular. But as I try to use ng-repeat i get an error and i am unable to understand whats the problem

app.component.html

```
<h1>hi </h1>

<br><br><br>

<select>
  <option ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  names = ["Pending", "Out for delivery", "Delivered"];

  title = 'dropdownproj';
}
```

can someone help me out with this. It might be a silly mistake but i cant get a hold of it. Help!

error i get

```
Property 'x' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` really...:) ? we use `ngFor` in angular 2+ versions

Comment: i was trying out stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<select>
        <option *ngFor="let x of names" [value]="x">
          {{x}}
        </option>
    </select>
```